# Что за странные очереди автоматически создаются в RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

Есть экосистема микросервисов, представляющих из себя ASP.NET апликейшены, работающие под IIS и общающиеся друг с другом по RabbitMQ с помощью библиотеки MassTransit. Недавно мы обнаружили, что при выполнении некоторых операций и распространении сообщений в RabbitMQ автоматически генерируются очереди вида:
[image: n]

При этом происходит попытка доставить сообщение на эту очередь, так, будто у нее есть консьюмер типа распространяемого сообщения, после чего, все такие сообщения падают в очередь skipped.

Вот пример такого сообщения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно за час в очереди skipped может накопится много таких сообщений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потери каких-то данных или дублей не происходит, насколько я могу наблюдать, просто сообщения накапливаются в очереди skipped, их приходится постоянно чистить вручную. Насколько я понимаю, проблему можно решить избавившись от этой странной очереди, которая создается сама по себе. Но мне не ясна природа её возникновения. Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с чем-то подобным?

Answer (score 1):

Имя этой очереди, как и параметр temporary, намекают что это временная очередь для ловли ответов на RPC-запросы.

Если эти ответы не ловятся, а пропускаются - разбирайтесь с приложением-создателем очереди, такого быть не должно. В норме подобные очереди должны слушаться библиотекой без участия программиста, если только тот чего-то намеренно не поломал.

Однако, в вашем вопросе я не вижу примера сообщения отправленного в эту очередь, я вижу лишь сообщение отправленное в обычную очередь, а указанная вами очередь со странным именем является лишь указанием куда слать ответ.